# How can I include the layout.xml file in the project in the new version android studio?

Tags: kotlin, android-studio

Hello There I started learning Kotlin language. In the past, design and so on via layout.xml. We were making things and automatically adding them to the project. Now I want to create a new layout.xml in the new version and include it in the project, but it doesn't work. how can I do it ?

I tried most of chatgpt etc. AIs but I couldn't get any results even from them.

Answer (score 3):

The "Empty Activity" new-project wizard in Android Studio Giraffe now creates a Jetpack Compose project.

To create a Views-based project (that use xml files to define layouts), select one of the templates that has "Views" in its name.

Once you have a Views-based project, you can add new layouts by creating files inside the `app/src/main/res/layout*` folders.

(I recommend taking a look at Jetpack Compose for new projects or adding new UIs to an existing application. It's a much nicer experience.)